# I'm getting float axis even with the command MaxNlocator(integer=True)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have this df called `normales`:

```
      CODIGO         MES  TMAX  TMIN     PP
0     000130       Enero  31.3  23.5   51.1
1     000130     Febrero  31.7  23.8  136.7
2     000130       Marzo  31.8  23.9  119.5
3     000130       Abril  31.5  23.7   55.6
4     000130        Mayo  30.6  23.1   15.6
     ...         ...   ...   ...    ...
4447  158328      Agosto  11.9 -10.6    2.2
4448  158328  Septiembre  13.2  -9.1    1.2
4449  158328     Octubre  14.6  -8.2    4.9
4450  158328   Noviembre  15.4  -7.2   11.1
4451  158328   Diciembre  14.7  -5.3   35.9
```

With this code i'm plotting time series and bars:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
for code, data in normales.groupby('CODIGO'):
    

    fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(4, sharex=False, sharey=False,figsize=(20, 15))
    data.plot('MES',["TMAX"], alpha=0.5, color='red', marker='P', fontsize = 15.0,ax=ax1)

    data.plot('MES',["TMIN"], alpha=0.5,color='blue',marker='D', fontsize = 15.0,ax=ax2)

    data.plot('MES',["PP"],kind='bar',color='green', fontsize = 15.0,ax=ax3)
    
    tabla=ax4.table(cellText=data[['TMAX','TMIN','PP']].T.values,colLabels=["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto",
                         "Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"],
              rowLabels=data[['TMAX','TMIN','PP']].columns,rowColours =["red","blue","green"],  
        colColours =["black"] * 12,loc="center",bbox = [0.0, -0.5, 1, 1])
    tabla.auto_set_font_size(False)
    tabla.set_fontsize(15)
    tabla.scale(1,2)
    ax4.axis('off')
    
    ax1.set_ylabel("Temperatura\nMáxima °C/mes", fontsize = 15.0)
    ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
    ax2.set_ylabel("Temperatura\nMínima °C/mes", fontsize = 15.0)
    ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
    ax3.set_ylabel("Precipitación mm/mes", fontsize = 15.0)
    ax3.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
    ax1.set_xlabel("")
    ax2.set_xlabel("")
    ax3.set_xlabel("")
    ax4.set_xlabel("")
```

You can realize that i'm using `ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))` in every axis to make integer the numbers of the axis. Although i'm using `ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))` i'm getting graphics with non integer (float) values in the yaxis. Do you know why this is happening?
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add a python tag. Please do not show your entire code. Please make a fully self-contained MCVE that illustrates the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`MaxNLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator) docs:

> **integer** bool, default: False
>
> If True, ticks will take only integer values, provided at least *min_n_ticks* integers are found within the view limits.
>
> ....
>
> **min_n_ticks** int, default: 2

You need to change `min_n_ticks` to `1` since `ax2` only has *one* integer within the view limits, namely `12`.

Comment: Thanks but some graphics have more than 1 tick. That's maybe an issue.

Comment: @Javier - not sure I follow, does `ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True, min_n_ticks=1))` not accomplish what you want? I understood that you want `ax2` to only have one tick, at `12`. Adding `min_n_ticks` doesn't mean that the Axes will only have one tick, it just means that the minimum number of ticks it'll have is 1.

Comment: Is not solving because i'm plotting many graphics, and not all graphics have just one integer value in the yaxis. That's why i showed this part of the code `for code, data in normales.groupby('CODIGO'):` I only showed one of the graphs where that problem occurred

Comment: @Javier - did you see my comment? Adding `min_n_ticks` doesn't mean that the Axes will have only one tick, it just means that *at minimum* it'll have one tick. Tested with your sample data, and for example `ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True, min_n_ticks=1))` and `ax3.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True, min_n_ticks=1))` preserve the multiple integer ticks on `ax1` and `ax3`.